# How to open a file that has a special character in it such as $?

Tags: perl, special-characters

Seems fairly simple but with the "$" in the name causes the name to split. I tried escaping the character out but when I try to open the file I get GLOB().

```
my $path = 'C:\dir\name$.txt';
open my $file, '<', $path || die
print "file = $file\n";
```

It should open the file so I can traverse the entries.

Comment: Semicolon missing after `open`, also, `($path || die)` will never die, use `or`.

Comment: semicolon was a typo when I typed into SO. Also that is right about the filehandle. I am actually more concerned about opening a file with a special character in it.

Comment: What were you expecting that to print out?

Comment: Just to be able to see the content of the file.

Comment: You haven't confirmed that the file was NOT opened. Try `print "file = ", <$file>` instead to see if the file can be read.

Comment: I get blank after "file ="

Comment: It works now. I got a blank because I was not pointing to a valid file.

Comment: What if the path and file were separate variables such as $path and $file. How can I combine these to work in this scenario?

Comment: @Opethian Can you elaborate? $path and $file are always separate variables. In your example the first is the file path (name) and the second is the file handle (what you can read from).

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the "$". Just follow standard file handling procedure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;   

my $path = 'C:\dir\name$.txt';
open my $file_handle, '<', $path or die "Can't open $path: $!";

# read and print the file line by line
while (my $line = <$file_handle>) {
    # the <> in scalar context gets one line from the file
    print $line;
}

# reset the handle
seek $file_handle, 0, 0;

# read the whole file at once, print it
{
    # enclose in a block to localize the $/ 
    #     $/ is the line separator, so when it's set to undef,
    #     it reads the whole file
    local $/ = undef;
    my $file_content = <$file_handle>;
    print $file_content;
}
```

Comment: The `print <$file_handle>` will surely produce the whole file (even without messing with `$/`) since `print` imposes the list context and the `<>` returns all lines; to make your point I'd suggest to assign to a scalar, like `my $content = <$file_handle>; print $content;`.  @Shawn: fixed

Comment: I took the liberty to make those changes.  Please by all means roll back what you don't like.  Another note: don't have to actually assign `undef`, just `local $/;` undefines it.  (However, explicit `undef` can be claimed as documenting it, even though I'd disagree.)

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. You are right of course.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the CPAN modules [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) which will handle the exact details of using open and readline, checking for errors, and encoding if appropriate (most text files are encoded to UTF-8).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurper 'read_text';
my $file_content = read_text $path;

use Path::Tiny 'path';
my $file_content = path($path)->slurp_utf8;
```

If it's a data file, use `read_binary` or `slurp_raw`.